# Javac not recognised even after setting variable path, Windows 10?

Tags: java, command-prompt, javac

I'm getting an error when typing `javac` in command prompt.

```
C:\Users\HP>javac

javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\HP>set path
path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10\bin\javaw.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10\bin;
PATHEXT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Documents;
```

I have already set `Path` in both system and user scope environment varible?

Comment: `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin"`

Answer (score 4):

You may set 2 system variable from console:

```
set JAVA_HOME="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

then your command "javac" will be found.

Comment: This is not correct syntax for DOS/Windows. You need to quote `PATH` because it has spaces in it. See my comment above for the correct syntax.

Comment: `set "JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"` (see position of opening double quotes).

Comment: I used your answer to fix issue with java not found in Windows Server and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` variable looks corrupted. Moreover, the `PATHEXT` variable is totally confused. Their [default value in Windows 7/10/2008 (assuming the system drive is `C:`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) should be as follows:

```
PATH    C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;{plus program paths}
PATHEXT .COM; .EXE; .BAT; .CMD; .VBS; .VBE; .JS ; .WSF; .WSH; .MSC
```

Check output from `SET PATH` in a freshly open `cmd` window. If `path` and `pathext` look as above then use (modify directory names to match current Java version):

```
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

Above setting is temporary (would last only for current `cmd` session). For persistent solution, there are more tutorials on the net e.g. [How To Set Java Path & Java Home Variables (Windows, MacOS, Ubuntu)](https://explainjava.com/java-path/).

Answer (score 0):

> Try out the following solutions.

1. `Close your current cmd` and `Open a new cmd.exe`
2. `Restart the computer`

**NOTE:** If `cmd` is open when you set the environment variables, then, that property will not be available until unless you `open new cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, the problem of 'javac is not recognized ...' can be fixed in these 4 steps:

**Step 1:**   Install JDK to specific path (Example: C:\jdk-15)

**Step 2:**   Setup JAVA_HOME environment variable to the installation folder

```
   Windows --> Advanced settings --> Environment variables --> System Variable 
   
   --> Add new variable  

   JAVA_HOME  =  C:\jdk-15
```

**Step 3:**  Prefix JAVA_HOME\bin to PATH variable of Windows

```
 Windows --> Advanced settings --> Environment variables --> System Variables 

 --> Update PATH variable


 PATH =  JAVA_HOME\bin;..... old value of PATH variable ....
```

**Step 4:**  Try the javac and java commands in new command window

**Note:** Already opened command windows will not take the new values of JAVA_HOME or PATH. The test needs to be done in new window opened after the environment variables are changed and saved.

```
C:\Users\user1> javac -version

C:\Users\user1> java -version
```